# If $(f_n)$ is a pointwise convergent, uniformly bounded sequence of measurable functions on I, then its limit $f$ is also measurable.

Tags: real-analysis

If $(f_n)$ is a pointwise convergent, uniformly bounded sequence of measurable functions on $I:[0,1]$, then its limit $f$ is also measurable.

I think I will use the property that since it is pointwise convergent, we have $\lim \sup a_n = \lim \inf a_n$. But how can I prove the sup/inf is measurable? Is there any proposition could help?

Comment: Uniform boundedness is not needed.

Comment: Does the boundedness indicates the existence of sup and inf?

Comment: No, supremum and infimum do not have to be finite (and neither do measurable functions).

Answer (score 2):

Let $f = \sup_{n\geq 1} f_n$. Notice that
$$f^{-1}((-\infty,a]) = \{x : f_n(x) \leq a, n \geq 1\} = \cap_{n=1}^\infty f_n^{-1}((-\infty,a]),$$
which is a countable sequence of measurable sets, hence measurable.